# Why that the process' comm value is from last 15 characters of process name but the thread's comm value is from top 15 characters?

Tags: proc

I'm developing on Android 11 device. I am confused that the process' comm value is from last 15 characters of process name but the thread's comm value is from top 15 characters. Does any man page explain this?

For example:

```
console:/ # cat /proc/5455/comm                                                
ndroid.launcher
console:/ # cat /proc/5455/task/5470/comm                                      
ReferenceQueueD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process can set its own comm value arbitrarily, just by writing to /proc/self/comm.

Due to your system being Android and not regular Linux, it would be reasonable to assume that the Android "app" runtime manually sets its comm value to whatever would be most useful – and as Android app IDs are in the "reverse DNS" format, their last components are the most useful ones for quick identification.

Comment: I think you are right.